# In Python dataclasses, why can an InitVar have default but not a default_factory?

Tags: python, api-design, python-dataclasses

In Python 3.7, I can create a *dataclass* with a defaulted `InitVar` just fine:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, InitVar, field

@dataclass
class Foo:
    seed: InitVar[str] = field(default='tomato')
    stored: str = field(init=False)

    def __post_init__(self, seed: str):
        self.stored = f'planted {seed}'

print(Foo())
```

Now I try to create a similar *dataclass* with a **mutable** default, for which I need to use `default_factory` instead:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, InitVar, field
from typing import List

@dataclass
class Bar:
    seeds: InitVar[List[str]] = field(default_factory=list)
    stored: List[str] = field(init=False)

    def __post_init__(self, seeds: List[str]):
        self.stored = [f'planted {seed}' for seed in seeds]

print(Bar())
```

However, this is not valid. Python raises `TypeError: field seeds cannot have a default factory`.

The `dataclasses.py` file from the standard library does not explain why:

```py
    # Special restrictions for ClassVar and InitVar.
    if f._field_type in (_FIELD_CLASSVAR, _FIELD_INITVAR):
        if f.default_factory is not MISSING:
            raise TypeError(f'field {f.name} cannot have a '
                            'default factory')
        # Should I check for other field settings? default_factory
        # seems the most serious to check for.  Maybe add others.  For
        # example, how about init=False (or really,
        # init=<not-the-default-init-value>)?  It makes no sense for
        # ClassVar and InitVar to specify init=<anything>.
```

Why? What is the rationale behind this special restriction? How does this make sense?

Comment: I would expect because you can write code in `__post_init__` to handle this case, with the idiomatic Python `if foo is None: foo = []`. Non-post-init values don’t have that luxury and *need* a factory. Having both a factory and custom post-init processing may be deemed potentially confusing…?

Comment: I wonder if there's some corner case where the factory could be invoked in `__post_init__` without knowing that it was already invoked in `__init__`. This code only exists in the commit that introduced `dataclasses.py`, so no help from the Git log. Your best chance at a definitive answer might be to ask on one of the mailing lists, where the original author could provide some insight. (Not sure which mailing list would be most appropriate: `python-dev` or `python-help`, perhaps.)

Comment: This one really has me stumped. The comments in code and tests all imply that it is obvious why InitVar default factories make no sense, but I just don't see why.

Comment: I have asked in python-help now: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.python/hskZcjZfm40

Comment: The author does not remember, but I will continue investigating. https://github.com/ericvsmith/dataclasses/issues/147

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The rationale is that supplying a `default_factory` would almost always be an error.

The intent of `InitVar` is to create a pseudo-field, called an "init-only field".  That is almost always populated by `post_init()` if the value is other than the default. It is never returned by module-level fields() function.  The primary use case is initializing field values that depend on one or more other fields.

Given this intent, it would almost always be a user error to supply a `default_factory` which is:

1. Something we would want to see returned by the `fields()` function.
2. Entirely unnecessary if we're using `post_init()` where you can call a factory directly.
3. Not suited for the case where the object creation depends on other field values.

Comment: Just had a "duh!" moment after all this time brought to me by this sentence: "Entirely unnecessary if we're using post_init() where you can call a factory directly."  thank you, @raymond-hettinger